# DNS over TLS (DoT) not working in 20.10

Tags: networking, server, dns

I first started by simply adding the dns address of the server I wanted to use in Network Manager, but that didn't work.

[image]

Then I tried editing /etc/systemd/resolved.conf:

```
[Resolve]
DNS=95.216.24.230
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
DNSSEC=yes
DNSOverTLS=yes
#MulticastDNS=no
#LLMNR=no
#Cache=no-negative
DNSStubListener=yes
#ReadEtcHosts=yes
#ResolveUnicastSingleLabel=no
```

That didn't work either. Browser is unusable. However, when I revert to my ips dns or other simple dns servers (and comment out all entries in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf), everything works fine. I have tried other DoT servers also, none of them work for me. I checked other posts on this subject but they all seem to refer to 18.04. I am on 20.10 and things have changed since then. I am not sure if I should be editing through netplan or /etc/systemd/resolved.conf. Actually, I thought this would be a simple procedure of just inserting the ip of the dns server into Network Manager, but obviously it is not.

Comment: Network Manager doesn't support DoT in itself.  If you want to do DoT you need to set up a DoT server endpoint such as Stubby on your computer and point all your DNS lookups to that component for DoT to work.  Also, DoT needs to be supported by the endpoint DNS server, not all support it.

Comment: Stubby was necessary years ago, but luckily things have improved since then and it is no longer necessary. Enabling DoT is actually quite simple now. Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For others who may be struggling with the same thing, the answer is to ignore Network Manager. Turn off auto in the DNS section and leave the dns field blank in Network Manager. Then nano /etc/systemd/resolved.conf and set like this:

```
[Resolve]
DNS=your.dns.ip#server.name
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
DNSSEC=true
DNSOverTLS=true
#MulticastDNS=no
#LLMNR=no
#Cache=no-negative
#DNSStubListener=yes
#ReadEtcHosts=yes
#ResolveUnicastSingleLabel=no
```

The trick is that you must set DNS= to ip PLUS '#' plus server name for DNSOverTLS=true to work. This is because the server's certificate must be validated in order to proceed. If you don't provide the server's name, your machine cannot validate it. "Opportunistic" will work here but will not validate and open several vulnerabilities so is not a good choice. Also, obviously, the DNS server you are connecting to must support DoT.

After this run:

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service
```

and you should be good to go.

Thanks to Thomas Ward for pointing out the potential problems with the "opportunistic" setting and a clue to figuring out how to do it right.

Comment: opportunistic means if DoT isn't available it'll drop to non-DoT.  This is probably not what you're after... just a thought.

Comment: I know that is what it means, however "true" and "yes" do not work. I'm not sure why. Do you know if there is another word to use for here? Since I know the server I am using has DoT enabled, I'm assuming "opportunistic" won't be an issue. The main thing is that it works.

Comment: look at the manpage `man resolved.conf 5` in the command line, the DNSoverTLS section is what you want.  If the remote DNS server doesn't have a valid certificate for it, then that'll be one of the reasons your "yes" or "true" was failing - opportunistic won't validate the remote tls certificate, but "yes" or "true" will - chances are this was your issue (and there's data in syslog about it failing to validate)

Comment: Good observation! I read the man page you suggested and the answer was there: you have to add "#server.name" to the tail of the ip. Then I switched DNSOverTLS to "true" and everything works (and the vulnerabilities that come with "opportunistic" are abolished)!  Thanks :-)